# find specific folders with size 0 under directory using batch

Tags: batch-file

can someone please help how to find specific folders with size 0 under directory using batch? thank you.

there are many folders in a parent folder, some of them have files inside and some folder are empty. I'd like to find out the name of the empty folders using batch file. can someone help? thanks

Comment: When you have a Linux subsystem on your computer, you might use the `du` basic UNIX command, like `cd /mnt/c/Temp_Folder`, `du -k empty_folder/`.

Comment: Directories do not have a size, _(the size I think you mean is the total size of all files it contains)_. So could you please clarify whether you're looking for, directories which contain no files? directories which contain no files and no directories? or even perhaps, directories which contain no files or directories, except for symlinks/junctions? In addition to that clarification, as this site is not a code request service, nor are its members interactive search robots, please edit your question to provide the code you've tried, and explain how it fails to work as it was intended to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script scans the target folder and returns the UNC paths of all empty subfolders within the target folder.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM This script scans the target folder and returns the UNC paths of all empty subfolders within the target folder.

title Looking for empties, please wait!
cd "%~dp0"
cls

if "%~1" == "" (
    echo ERROR: No folder was specified!  You gotta tell me where to look for empties!
    echo      Please drag-and-drop a folder onto the icon for this script.
    pause
    exit /b
)

if not exist "%~dpn1" (
    echo ERROR: The folder you told me to scan doesn't seem to exist!
    pause
    exit /b
)

set "target=%~dpn1"
echo Scanning: %target%
echo.

REM Grab each subfolder for checking.
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%~dpn1" /s /b /a:d') do (call :checkForBlanks "%%a")

echo.
echo Done.
title Done.
pause
exit /b

:checkForBlanks
    REM We've been given a folder.  We must check if it's empty.
    set "folder=%~1"
    set "scanned=!folder:%target%=!"
    title Looking for empties: %scanned:&=^&%
    set exist=
    for /f %%a in ('dir "%~1" /b') do (set "exist=%%a" & goto :found)
    :found
    if "%exist%" == "" echo EMPTY: %scanned:&=^&%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) idea, which leverages [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) may provide the information you require.

I say, may, because you've not clarified what you deem to be an empty subfolder, or folder with size 0.

The following single line batch file example should work regardless of the installed `powershell.exe` version:

```batch-file
@(For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "(GCI -Rec|?{$_.PSIsContainer -Eq $True})|?{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -Eq 0}|Select -Exp FullName" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo/%%G)&Pause
```

If you're using a more up to date version of `powershell.exe`, perhaps the following example may be preferable for you:

```batch-file
@(For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "GCI -AD -S|?{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -Eq 0}|Select -Exp FullName" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo/%%G)&Pause
```

Both examples are designed to recurse from the current directory, if you wish to insert the base directory directly into the for loop then use it just after `GCI` in whichever example you choose, *(preferable enclosed between single straight quotes)*